# How to filter multiple extjs grid columns?

Tags: extjs, filter, grid, extjs4, store

To filter one grid column we can use:

```
{
     xtype: 'button',
     text:'Search',
     handler:function(){

        store.clearFilter();
        var searchValue = Ext.getCmp("textFieldId").getValue();
        store.load().filter('GridFieldName', searchValue);

     }                   
}
```

but how to search multiple fields at once, something like:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text:'Search',
    handler:function(){

        store.clearFilter();
        var searchValue = Ext.getCmp("textFieldId").getValue();
        store.filter([
           {property: "GridFieldName", value: searchValue},
           {property: "GridFieldName1", value: searchValue}
        ]);
    }                   

}
```

any ideas?

**EDIT:**

The weird thing is that in both cases, only single search works:

This works:

```
store.filter([
      { property: "FirstName", value: searchValue }
]);
```

and this works:

```
var FirstNameFilter = new Ext.util.Filter({
   property: "FirstName", value: searchValue
});

store.filter(FirstNameFilter);
```

but this does not:

```
store.filter([
      { property: "FirstName", value: searchValue },
      { property: "LastName", value: searchValue }
]);
```

or does this:

```
 var filters = [
     new Ext.util.Filter({
          property: "FirstName", value: searchValue
     }),
     new Ext.util.Filter({
          property: "LastName", value: searchValue
     })
 ];
 store.filter(filters);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to create instances of `Ext.util.Filter` like this:

```
var filters = [
 new Ext.util.Filter({
  property: "GridFieldName", value: searchValue
 }),
 new Ext.util.Filter({
  property: "GridFieldName1", value: searchValue
 })
];
store.filter(filters);
```

Alternatively, you can create single filter with custom logic:

```
var filters = [
     new Ext.util.Filter({
      filterFn: function(item){
         return item.get('GridFieldName') == searchValue && item.get('GridFieldName1') == searchValue;
      }
     })
];
store.filter(filters);
```

Comment: Not only did the OP mention that this does not work but I am using 3.2 (being forced to) and Ext.util.Filter doesn't exist. Any suggestions?

Comment: hello this code filter check both field if both in available then and then return result

Comment: i need if any one field in find then return i try "||" but it's not working

Answer (score 8):

I found this post while searching for a way to filter on multiple columns (actually ALL columns) with OR logic. (so the search-clause matches column A OR matches column B etc.) I ended up filtering with a custom filterfunction like:

```
...
var regex = RegExp('Insert searchclause here', 'i');
store.filter(new Ext.util.Filter({
    filterFn: function (object) {
        var match = false;
        Ext.Object.each(object.data, function (property, value) {
            match = match || regex.test(String(value));
        });
        return match;
      }
}));
```

HTH

Answer (score 5):

```
    store.clearFilter();
    var searchValue = Ext.getCmp("textFieldId").getValue();
    if (!!searchValue) {
        var filters = [
             new Ext.util.Filter({
                 filterFn: function (item) {
                     return item.get('FirstName').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase()) > -1                                 
                         || item.get('LastName').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase()) > -1;
                 }
             })
        ];
        store.filter(filters);
    }
```

This is my code which apply from Pavel.
For my work which search **Multi-column, Non-case sensitive, Ignore position** by `OR` logic.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

That should work. Is it not? As I understand it if you apply filters as you have shown, it should filter by both criteria.

```
store.filter([
   {property: "GridFieldName", value: searchValue},
   {property: "GridFieldName1", value: searchValue}
]);
```

As an alternative you should be able to use the setFilter function to add new filters.

```
store.setFilter("GridFieldName",  searchValue)
store.setFilter("GridFieldName1",  searchValue)
```

If you use setFilter with no arguments it should just reapply the filters you have previously defined. They are only removed if you call clearFilter.

Comment: Which one filtered, firstName or LastName?

Comment: well, none if you put both filters, only works with one, i need to lets say, filter whole json for searchValue, so i need multiple filters on multiple columns?