# Can't filter multiple extjs grid columns

Tags: extjs, filter, grid, extjs4, store

To filter one grid column I use:

```
store.filter({
          property: 'first_name',
          anyMatch: true,
          value   : this.getValue()
      });
```

Now I need to search multiple fields at once, something like:

```
      var filters = [
    new Ext.util.Filter({
    property: "first_name", anyMatch: true, value: this.getValue()
    }),
    new Ext.util.Filter({
   property: "last_name", anyMatch: true, value: this.getValue()
   })
 ];
  store.filter(filters);
```

**The weird thing is that in both cases, only single search works**

this didn't help [How to filter multiple extjs grid columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996028/how-to-filter-multiple-extjs-grid-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the way you implement the Filter I guess you are using `remoteSort: false` As hint: You don't need to create a instance of the filter, just provide the configuration. If possible spare `this`. Most events provide a instance of the component, use it instead of `this`. It can save you headache.

I tested it and it works. Here's a simple example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data:{'items':[
        { 'name': 'Lisa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-111-1224"  },
        { 'name': 'Lisam',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1234" },
        { 'name': 'Bart',  "email":"bart@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1234" },
        { 'name': 'Homer', "email":"home@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1244"  },
        { 'name': 'Marge', "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"  }
    ]},
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    tbar: [{
        text: 'filter',
        handler: function(btn) {
            var g = btn.up('grid');
            g.store.filter([{property: "name", anyMatch: true, value: 'Lisa'},{property: "email", anyMatch: true, value: 'lisa@simpsons.com'}])
        }
    }],
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Here is a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BvDjH/)**

**Version 2** *with textfield*

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data:{'items':[
        { 'name': 'Lisa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-111-1224"  },
        { 'name': 'Lisam',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1234" },
        { 'name': 'Bart',  "email":"bart@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1234" },
        { 'name': 'Homer', "email":"home@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1244"  },
        { 'name': 'Marge', "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"  }
    ]},
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    tbar: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        emptyText: 'filter',
        listeners: {
            specialkey: function(field, e){
                if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
                    var g = field.up('grid'),
                        value = field.getValue(); 
                    g.store.filter({scope: this, filterFn: function(rec) { 
                    var rege = new RegExp(".*" + value + ".*"); 
                    if (rege.test(rec.data.name) || rege.test(rec.data.email)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                } 
            });
                }
            }
        }
    }],
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});​
```

And the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BvDjH/1/)**

Comment: Okay, when I use : `store.filter([{property: "first_name", anyMatch: true, value: this.getValue()},{property: "last_name", anyMatch: true, value: this.getValue()}]);`  it worked but as an AND condition, like when user types 'ma' .. it retrieved the names but only those contains 'ma' in both first and last names. I need it to be OR. How can I do this ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Noon You have to write a custom filterFn for that cause the filters are always concatenated with `AND`. I will update my post as soon as I find some time

Comment: @Noon See my edit which now also uses a textfield (hit return for search)

Comment: great! Now I just need the OR condition thing

Comment: @Noon It is already there. See; `if (rege.test(rec.data.name) || rege.test(rec.data.email))` The tests are combined as `OR` so only one condition need to be true and you will get a result.